# Tarjan's Algorithm implementation, Low value node issue

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, tarjans-algorithm, strongly-connected-graph

I am trying to execute tarjans algorithm on a set of nodes from a graph, I can succesfully find Strongly Connected Components, however the root or the low value node is always off, even for SCC's with only 1 element the root node does not match that element
For Example:

```
0-3 IS LOW VALUE NODE
[82-97]
529-529 IS LOW VALUE NODE
[69-81]
379-379 IS LOW VALUE NODE
[57-68]
1619-1619 IS LOW VALUE NODE
[136-137]
415-415 IS LOW VALUE NODE
[45-56]
```

where the top is the low value node and the bottom is the 1 element that makes up the SCC

The code I currently have is here

```
package Structs;

import java.util.*;

public class TarjanSCC {

    private int id;
    private boolean[] onStack;
    private int[] ids, low;
    private Deque<Integer> stack;
    private Graph<BasicBlock> graph;
    private Map<BasicBlock, Integer> nodeMap;
    private BasicBlock[] nodes;
    private static final int UNVISITED = -1;

    public TarjanSCC(Graph<BasicBlock> graph) {
        this.graph = graph;
    }

    public void runTSCC() {
        runTSCC(graph);
    }

    public void runTSCC(Graph<BasicBlock> nodeGraph) {

        //Initialize values for sorting
        this.nodes = nodeGraph.getNodes().toArray(new BasicBlock[nodeGraph.size()]);
        int size = nodes.length;
        this.ids = new int[size];
        this.low = new int[size];
        this.onStack = new boolean[size];
        this.stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        this.nodeMap = new HashMap<>();

        //Mark all nodes as unused, place nodes in a map so index is easily retrievable from node
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            nodeMap.put(nodes[i], i);
            ids[i] = UNVISITED;
        }

        //Invoke the DFS algorithm on each unvisited node
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (ids[i] == UNVISITED) dfs(i, nodeGraph);
        }
    }

    private void dfs(int at, Graph<BasicBlock> nodeGraph) {
        ids[at] = low[at] = id++;
        stack.push(at);
        onStack[at] = true;

        //Visit All Neighbours of graph and mark as visited and add to stack,
        for (BasicBlock edge : nodeGraph.getEdges(nodes[at])) {
            int nodeArrayIndex = nodeMap.get(edge);
            if (ids[nodeArrayIndex] == UNVISITED) {
                dfs(nodeArrayIndex, nodeGraph);
                low[at] = Math.min(low[at], low[nodeArrayIndex]);
            }
            else if (onStack[nodeArrayIndex]) low[at] = Math.min(low[at], nodeArrayIndex);
        }

        //We've visited all the neighours, lets start emptying the stack until we're at the start of the SCC
        if (low[at] == ids[at]) {
            List<BasicBlock> sccList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int node = stack.pop();; node = stack.pop()) {
                onStack[node] = false;
                sccList.add(0, nodes[node]);
                if (node == at) {
                    System.out.println(nodes[low[at]] + " IS LOW VALUE NODE");
                    System.out.println(sccList);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect the issue lies with setting the low values.
I do not believe any other class info is required as there is no issues with retrieving edges from the graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was indexing the root node wrong nodes[at] is the proper way to access the root node